# can Intellij filter class implementation

Tags: intellij-idea

For example , I use Ctrl+Alt+B(intellij IDEA 2018) to find java.util.Collection's implementations,but all dependencies's Collection implementations come out. Is there anyway to confine these to a scope or filter the result(something similar to 'find' using Ctrl +Shift +F)?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

After selecting the interface method you are interested in, you can do that via: Menu Bar --> Edit --> Find --> Find Usages Settings  (Ctrl-Alt-Shift-F7)

There you can select "Overriding Methods" instead of "Usages" and define a scope.

**Example**

For the method AbstractList.add(int index, E element) I defined MySpecialScope for only two packages (just as an example) without recursive include.

[image]

Then the result were only the 6 implementations of the method add() in java.util.*

[image: **enter image description here**]

Many others like e.g. the one in javax.management.AttributeList (from rt.jar) were not listed.